# React-redux: allowing users to give feedback on a component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am returning a list of forecasts from my back end, which is rendered in a dashboard (I'm making the API call in componentWillMount()). Each forecast is rendered as a presentational component and has a like and dislike button. Once the user clicks on the button, a an Axios action is called which posts an event to the back end REST API saving this feedback.

As I see it, I don't need to deal with Redux's state here, unless I want to disable the buttons or otherwise change them when clicked. All I want to do here is to 1) trigger a CSS animation on the button (some sort of bounce) to let the user know he clicked it, and if the Axios action returns an error, I need to display it in an error section.

The issue is that I have not been able to figure out how to do this without going through the rigamarole of dispatching the Axios result to state, putting it through a reducer, then mapping state to props in the component, etc. This seems overkill for something this transitory, no?

Comment: you can just use axios directly without using any reducers. but the css part would require the component to re-render. - to add new className or what so you can use css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. As @ReiDien stated

> you can just use axios directly without using any reducers.

As for the animation and the error message you can use your component's state to store these. You may need a container component to handle the state and its changes. Your handler ends up as something like:

```
handleLike = () => {
  this.setState({
    liked: true,
  });
  axios.post(...)
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({
        error: error,
        liked: false
      });
    });
}
```